# Adding google maps in navigation drawer : Error in output (Maps not being displayed)

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation, navigation-drawer

I Have successfully integrated google maps in Navigation drawer layout in android studio. But when I call the activity somehow only the markers display. but the map part is blank. I would like to zoom in on the current location and that too is not happening.

**Question** :  **Why Maps are not being displayed properly**

**My Code**

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by Administrator on 18-12-2015.
 */
public class MapsActivity extends Fragment {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    MapView mapView;


    public MapsActivity() {
    }


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);

        mapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map);

        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(mapView!=null)
        {
            mMap = mapView.getMap();

            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

            LatLng Redfort = new LatLng(28.656061, 77.237847);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Redfort).title("Red Fort- Starting Point 1").snippet("Welcome"));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Redfort));


            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(29.656061, 77.237847))
                    .title("Delhi")
                    .snippet("Population: 776733"));
        }

        return rootView;
    }
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: did you add google api key in manifest.xml

Comment: i add code below check it once.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should implement `OnMapReadyCallback`,
You should set marker and use moveCamera method when map is ready, i.e. in method `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)` of `OnMapReadyCallback`,
Ref : https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback

Second : You must be getting some error log in logcat view, I think above issue might appear when Google Map API denies permission, if you can please post the whole error log related with map.

Make sure you are following the official getting started guide :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start

For your case I think use `MapFragment`, and its `getMapAsync (OnMapReadyCallback callback)` method will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

check following code

```
public class MapView extends AppCompatActivity{
GoogleMap mMap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_view);
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mMap = mapFragment.getMap();
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(29.656061, 77.237847))
                .title("Delhi")
                .snippet("Population: 776733"));
    }
}
```

activity_map_view.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar">
    </include>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/abovetab">
        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view_left"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/filter"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="your drawable folder image" 
        android:title="Filter" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/modify"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="your drawable folder image"
        android:title="Modify" />

</group>
```